# How to copy/recreate indexes, constraints, triggers etc in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore

Background:I needed to copy 2 tables from a backup to a production SQL Server database. Being new to SQL, I thought that I could just drop and insert into and it would work. So naive.

Is there any simple way to copy everything about the good tables (I restored them into a separate backup) into the tables I created in the production DB? I know how to view constraints using "right click on table - tasks - create script - create script using CREATE", but I don't know what to do with this information.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood correctly, go to database and:
1. Script Table As -> Create to... Now you got your table with all indexes and other stuff which in the table.
2. Create these table in your new database
3. Copy your data from backup tables to the new.

You can do this with (tablock) for example. Before copying info drop constraints and indexes in new table and then copy your data.
Or without dropping any objects update your index and stats with ALTER
https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017